# How do image focal points work in Craft 3?

Tags: image-transforms, craft-pro

How do image focal points work in Craft 3? I see the dot in the CP, but I'm unable to set the focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focal points are used mainly for when Asset transforms (i.e. cropping) are performed in Craft.  They tell Craft where it should focus on the image when performing these actions.

Comment: How would one get the focal point data (presumably as an X/Y in percentages) in a template? Is it `assetFieldName.getFocalPoint()`? (as a non-programmer, I find the Craft 3 Classes docs _very_ confusing for purposes of templating...)

Comment: I would like to know this as well...

Comment: Here it is! https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#property-focalpoint

Comment: @Sandwich {% if slide.backgroundImage.one.hasFocalPoint %}
    {% set x = slide.backgroundImage.one.focalPoint | first %}
    {% set y = slide.backgroundImage.one.focalPoint | last %}
    {{ x }}, {{ y }}
  {% endif %}

Answer (score 13):

While we’re piggybacking, here’s a snippet that goes one step further and generates the necessary CSS to position an untransformed image:

```html
{% set img = entry.headingImage.one %}

{% if img %}
    {% set imgStyles = "background-image: url('" ~ img.getUrl() ~ "');"|raw %}

    {% if img.hasFocalPoint %}
        {% set x = img.focalPoint | first * 100 ~ '%' %}
        {% set y = img.focalPoint | last * 100 ~ '%' %}
        {% set imgStyles = imgStyles ~ ' background-position: ' ~ [x, y]|join(' ') %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<div class="block-header" style="{{ imgStyles is defined ? imgStyles }}">
    <h1>Mmm, backgrounds</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Length values in CSS are space separated, not comma separated. Join(',') would make the browser disregard the second value. You should use join(' ') instead.

Comment: Good catch. I think I managed to overlook that as the X axis was all that was relevant to my implementation and browsers seem to respect that initial value despite the comma.

Comment: Just be aware that this method doesn't necessarily keep the focal point in the centre. For example, setting a focal point along the x-axis of `0.1` might actually require a background-position of 0% (not 10%) to keep it closest to the centre. It requires some more complex math to get it properly correct. Although for many cases this is "good enough".

Comment: For the record, this CSS Tricks article seems like it has the key to figuring out the exact BG position values given a desired focal point: https://css-tricks.com/focusing-background-image-precise-location-percentages/
Still working on how to convert this to Twig. Unfortunately, it may also need JS for fluidly-sized elements.

Answer (score 3):

To piggyback off Brad, Focal Points tell craft where to crop the image but can also be used to position background images.

Here's how you can get focal point positions:

```
  {% if slide.backgroundImage.one.hasFocalPoint %}
    {% set x = slide.backgroundImage.one.focalPoint | first %}
    {% set y = slide.backgroundImage.one.focalPoint | last %}
    {{ x }}, {{ y }}
  {% endif %}
```

This will return the focal point position at a decimal (ie .32, .55)

Comment: To get this working with CSS you need to multiply the number by 100 and add % after the number.