# Is there a way to reset the focal point in Craft?

Tags: assets, image, focal-point

As the question states. Is it possible to reset the focal point in the CMS?
I cannot see any obvious setting? 
If not could this perhaps be a feature request for a reset focal point button?

Answer (score 1):

if you're referring to an image focal point then...

[How do image focal points work in Craft 3?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26403/how-do-image-focal-points-work-in-craft-3)

help out somewhat...

Comment: I can't see any easy way to st this back to the default though (50%, 50%)...?